# How to find which Node.js app processes are causing the server to crash and fix them

Tags: node.js, server, cpanel

I created a Node.js app. On my computer, it works without any problem, but when I upload it to a web hosting service (fastcomet) using "Setup Node.js App" that in "cpanel", and try to run it, server grt crash.

I contacted the hosting company, and a representative explained to me that my app creates processes that get stuck. To get the server back up and running again, he had to kill those processes.

I'm pretty new at Node.js, and scared to do it again on the hosting service. Is there a tool that allows me to check on my computer which problematic processes the app produces and fix them?

Attached the image I received from the representative, of the processes he killed:

[image]

Attach the code of the app's operating file `server.js` (The full code of the application is in the `server` folder, at: https://github.com/YitshakS/ice-cloud):

```js
import bigmlRoute from "./routes/bigmlRoute.js";
import branchesRoute from "./routes/branchesRoute.js";
import cors from "cors";
import dateRoute from "./routes/dateRoute.js";
import "dotenv/config.js";
import express from "express";
import flavorsRoute from "./routes/flavorsRoute.js";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import settlementsRoute from "./routes/settlementsRoute.js";
import transactionsRoute from "./routes/transactionsRoute.js";
import weatherRoute from "./routes/weatherRoute.js";

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json({ limit: "50mb" }));

app.get("/", (_, res) => {
    res.send("server ok");
});

app.use("/bigml", bigmlRoute);
app.use("/branches", branchesRoute);
app.use("/date", dateRoute);
app.use("/flavors", flavorsRoute);
app.use("/settlements", settlementsRoute);
app.use("/transactions", transactionsRoute);
app.use("/transactionsSql", transactionsSqlRoute);
app.use("/weather", weatherRoute);

mongoose
    .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL)
    .then(() => console.log("MongoDB connected"))
    // .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    .catch(() => console.log("Error: MongoDB not connected"));

const port = process.env.port || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server on port http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```